# Safari 13.1 is blocking third party cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari, webkit, session-cookies

I have an iframe that is embedded on external websites.
That iframe performs some actions that require to record some cookies, one of them is login the user on the iframe source website.

I basically followed this: https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/

It worked but only when you use Safari on an incognito window when I try to do the same using a common tab the cookies are not stored.

**UPDATE:**

We found a workaround is not the best in the world but something is something.
We added a CNAME on the external website CNAME: example.externalwebsite.com -> example.com
We changed the iframe src=example.externalwebsite.com

In this scenario, the subdomain example.externalwebsite.com is able to set the cookie as usual.

GOOD PART: we found a way to make it work.

BAD PART: we had to ask any client to add the CNAME and update their websites to change the iframe sources but as I said something is something.

Comment: did you found any other solution? ^^

Comment: no, it was good enough for our client. If you find something new, please share it.

Comment: Is this still working?